# permission error when trying to install bower

Tags: macos, bower

I am trying to install **bower** in a Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6 but I keep getting stuck.

I have tried most of the already posted solutions but none of them have worked.

```
ran_polavieja@your-da-man:/% bower init
? name fgpstudio-fronend
? description Diseño Frontend para FGP Studio
? main file index.html
? keywords
? authors frangp
? license ISC
? homepage https://github.com/franpola/fgpstudio-fronend
? set currently installed components as dependencies? Yes
? add commonly ignored files to ignore list? Yes
? would you like to mark this package as private which prevents it from being accidentally published to the registry? Yes

{
  name: 'fgpstudio-fronend',
  description: 'Diseño Frontend para FGP Studio',
  main: 'index.html',
  authors: [
    'frangp'
  ],
  license: 'ISC',
  homepage: 'https://github.com/franpola/fgpstudio-fronend',
  private: true,
  ignore: [
    '**/.*',
    'node_modules',
    'bower_components',
    'test',
    'tests'
  ]
}

? Looks good? Yes
bower EACCES        EACCES: permission denied, open '/bower.json'

Stack trace:
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/bower.json'
    at Error (native)

Console trace:
Error
    at StandardRenderer.error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/renderers/StandardRenderer.js:81:37)
    at Logger.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/bin/bower.js:110:26)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Logger.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Logger.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/bower-logger/lib/Logger.js:29:39)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/commands/index.js:48:20
    at _rejected (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:844:24)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:870:30
    at Promise.when (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:1122:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:788:41)
System info:
Bower version: 1.8.0
Node version: 4.6.0
OS: Darwin 16.7.0 x64
```

Does anyone have a clue how can I get rid of that EACCES permission error?

Comment: Have you tried to run the command with sudo? Like 'sudo bower init' and provide your pwd.

Comment: yeah, I have tried almost everything. if I type it with sudo now it says bower ESUDO         Cannot be run with sudo

Additional error details:
Since bower is a user command, there is no need to execute it with superuser permissions. pwd is /

Comment: i am starting to think that everything that goes inside /usr/local.... is system protected because I can't seem to be able to take ownership of those directories..

Comment: It worked when run it from the specific path... you cant run a command if you are not on the directory..

Answer (score 0):

to be able to run a command you need to set your prompt path to the directory that contains that command0